# Node mock-fs library - /path/to/file is not being mocked

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, mock-fs

Unit testing my gulp app in Mocha and using `mock-fs` from the [mock-fs repo](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs) .

In my app code I have:

```js
    console.log('sssssssssssssss ' + srcFile);
    srcFile = fs.statSync(srcFile).mtime;
```

which shows `sssssssssssssss /home/one/foo`

In my test I have:

```js
        mock({
            home: {
              one: { 
                foo: mock.file({
                  content: 'nothing',
                  mtime: new Date(Date.now())
                })
              },
            },
            bar: mock.file({
            content: 'nothing',
            mtime: new Date(1,1)
            })
        });
```

But I get the following error when running the test:

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/one/foo'

What I am doing wrong so that `/home/one/foo` is not being mocked?

Comment: For anyone who arrives here after upgrading Node to v20.10.0+, https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/issues/384